# Uneven horizontal spacing for 3 subfigures

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am tryining to show 2 rows of subfigures where each row contains 3 subfigures. However, the horizontal spacing between the subfigures is unequal and also it seems to be different between the two rows? How can I get centered and equally spaced subfigures in the figure with little spacing between the subfigures?

My code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht] 
 \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testImage} 
    \label{fig7:a} 
    \vspace{1ex}
  \end{subfigure}%% 
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testImage} 
    \label{fig7:b} 
    \vspace{1ex}
  \end{subfigure} 
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testImage} 
   \label{fig7:c} 
   \vspace{1ex}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testImage} 
   \label{fig7:d} 
  \end{subfigure}%%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testImage} 
   \label{fig7:e} 
  \end{subfigure} 
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testImage} 
   \label{fig7:f} 
  \end{subfigure} 
  \label{fig7} 
 \end{figure}
```

The result image:

[image]

Comment: you have just `\hfill` in the narrow spaces and wide spaces have one inter-word space and `\hfill`, as  in some cases you have a space from the line end after `\end{subfigure}` and in others you have commented that space out

Comment: Thank you that is correct and solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testImage}
\label{fig7:a}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testImage}
\label{fig7:b}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testImage}
\label{fig7:c}
\end{subfigure}%

\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testImage}
\label{fig7:d}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testImage}
\label{fig7:e}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testImage}
\label{fig7:f}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{my figures}
\label{fig7}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

i only remove all necessary `\centering` and `\vspace{1ex}` inside environments `subfigure`, changes presence of `%` after `subfigure` environment (now is one after each `subfigure`) and insert  empty line after third image (and with it start new line).

Comment: Hm this still does give no equally spaced images for me. Does this also work for you if the images do not have a square format?

Comment: it works for any format of images. demo images are not square, but rectangle (their widths are is little bit larger than their heights). i edit my answer now, changed are only vertical space between images rows.

Comment: Okay I did overlook that you changed the comment symbol (%) after every subfigure. Now it works for me! Maybe you change your answer that you also changed the % symbols in comparison to my code.

Comment: @Marcel_marcel1991, done!